# Market Basket Analysis: How to deal with item sets with high Confidence, Lift, and ChiSquare but very low Support?

Tags: chi-squared-test, large-data, association-rules

I am doing a market basket analysis with a very large set of items, that is over 200000 individual items, with the majority of them occurring very rarely.

For this reason my analysis only focuses on item pairs disregarding any higher number of items in a set. I am also using half the number of individual item pairs (every pair appears twice) as my basis for the support, defining every item pair to be a transaction. Is this in any way problematic?

I'm doing the analysis according to [this](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/~odj/Teaching/dm/1%20Association%20Rules%2008.pdf) and [this](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/~odj/Teaching/dm/1%20Association%20Rules%2008.pdf) calculating the Support values, Confidence, Lift, and the $\chi^2$-test-value for each pair.

Now I tend to have lots of items which appear very rarely, that is they have very low Support (the full number of individual item pairs is over 46 million). But often items like that appear together with high Confidence and due to the low Support of the individual items their values for Lift and $\chi^2$ are very large suggesting that their combined occurrence is with almost certainty not by chance.

**Example:**

Consider two items A and B in a set with a total number of $N = 100000$.

Item A appears $1$ time, item B appears $10$ times, so they appear together $1$ time.

This leads to Supports $S(A)=\frac{N(A)}{N}=0.00001$, $S(B)=0.0001$, and $S(A \cap B) = 0.00001$

Confidence $C(A|B)=\frac{S(A \cap B)}{S(A)} = 1$

The Lift then becomes $L(A|B)=\frac{S(A \cap B)}{S(A)S(B)} = 10000$

And the $\chi^2$-value becomes $T=\frac{N(S(A \cap B)-S(A)S(B))^2}{S(A)S(B)(1-S(A))(1-S(B))} = 9999$

The values suggest that these two items appearing together means they belong together in a meaningful way, but it's only one occurrence at all.

**Question:**

Since my set has a very large number of sets, low values of individual Support are very common and by filtering everything below a certain threshold I'm losing lots of data.

Does the analysis like described hold for those low-Support events meaning that from those numbers alone those item pairings can be considered valid enough to be meaningful for the market basket analysis or should they be discarded?

EDIT: Corrected a few symbols.

Comment: In your example, item $A$ only appears once? or only once when item $B$ also occurs?  Also, you should have $P(A|B)=\frac{1}{10}=0.1$ if $A$ and $B$ occur together once, and item $B$ occurs $10$ times.

Comment: Item $A$ appears only once and the one time it appears it appears together with $B$. Also I corrected my formulas, I was using a wrong symbol.